# HttpWebRequest with html element - internal servor error

Tags: c#

I am trying to pass data to an HTML input element on a website using **HttpWebRequest** and to get back the response of my request with **WebResponse**.

You will find a screen shot of the form to be filled on internet and a screen shot of the response.

My problem is when running my code ,I always get a **response code 500 - internal server error**

[screen shot of the response on the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHyMY.png)

[screen shot of input html on the Website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Y1Uk.png)

I've updated my code in order to have a good format for my Data (thanks for this)

But I still get the same failure: **response code 500 - internal server error**.

Here is my updated c# code:

```
      //input html to be field 
            NameValueCollection Data = new NameValueCollection();
            Data.Add("bResultat", "true");
            Data.Add("ModeAffichage", "COMPLET");
            Data.Add("bImpression", "");
            Data.Add("AERO_Date_DATE", "2018/10/03");
            Data.Add("AERO_Date_HEURE", "20:50");
            Data.Add("AERO_Langue", "FR");
            Data.Add("AERO_Duree", "12");
            Data.Add("AERO_CM_REGLE", "1");
            Data.Add("AERO_CM_GPS", "2");
            Data.Add("AERO_CM_INFO_COMP", "1");
            Data.Add("AERO_Tab_Aero[0]", "EDDM");

            //Create the data in good format
            var parameters = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (string key in Data.Keys)
            {                    
               parameters.AppendFormat("{0}={1}&",
               System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(key),
               System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Data[key]));
            }
            parameters.Length -= 1;               

            byte[] bytedata = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(parameters.ToString());

            //request to server
            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://notamweb.aviation-civile.gouv.fr/Script/IHM/Bul_Aerodrome.php");
            req.Method = "POST";                
            req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            req.ContentLength = bytedata.Length;

            Stream reqStream = req.GetRequestStream();
            reqStream.Write(bytedata, 0, bytedata.Length);
            reqStream.Close();
            MessageBox.Show(bytedata.Length.ToString() + " - " + parameters);

            WebResponse response = req.GetResponse();
            var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

I hope you can help me to resolve my problem.

Comment: `Data.ToString()` will return the NameValueCollection's *type name* not the values converted to querystring format.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667150/is-converting-a-namevaluecollection-to-a-querystring-using-a-c-sharp-lambda-effi) for some conversion methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to inform you that i just have my first success.
I receive a response to my request.

I add the following parameter to my request:

```
req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.121 Safari/535.2";
```

My code is as follow:

```
//input html to be field 
            NameValueCollection Data = new NameValueCollection();
            Data.Add("bResultat", "true");
            Data.Add("ModeAffichage", "COMPLET");
            Data.Add("bImpression", "");
            Data.Add("AERO_Date_DATE", "2018/10/04");
            Data.Add("AERO_Date_HEURE", "21:50");
            Data.Add("AERO_Langue", "FR");
            Data.Add("AERO_Duree", "12");
            Data.Add("AERO_CM_REGLE", "1");
            Data.Add("AERO_CM_GPS", "2");
            Data.Add("AERO_CM_INFO_COMP", "1");
            Data.Add("AERO_Tab_Aero[0]", "EDDM");
            Data.Add("AERO_Tab_Aero[1]", "EDDF");
            Data.Add("AERO_Tab_Aero[2]", "EDDL");
            Data.Add("AERO_Tab_Aero[3]", "EDDV");
            Data.Add("AERO_Tab_Aero[4]", "EDDN");

            //Create the data in good format
            var parameters = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (string key in Data.Keys)
            {                    
               parameters.AppendFormat("{0}={1}&",
               System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(key),
               System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Data[key]));
            }
            parameters.Length -= 1;               

            byte[] bytedata = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(parameters.ToString());

            //request to server
            HttpWebRequest req =(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://notamweb.aviation-civile.gouv.fr/Script/IHM/Bul_Aerodrome.php");

            req.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
            req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.121 Safari/535.2";
            req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            req.ContentLength = bytedata.Length;

            Stream reqStream = req.GetRequestStream();
            reqStream.Write(bytedata, 0, bytedata.Length);
            reqStream.Close();
            MessageBox.Show(bytedata.Length.ToString() + " - " + parameters);

            WebResponse response = req.GetResponse();
            var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

I'm surprise to see that the Webresponse is embedded with HTML tag.
it will need to find a filter to clean it.
[WebResponse from the HttpWebRequest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NDSz.png)

Thanks for your advice

and see you for my next question

Cyrille

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of things to be improved in your example code. You should look at [`IDisposable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/using-objects) and `using` blocks to ensure resources are properly cleaned up when your application finishes using them. For example, you don't flush your request stream before closing it so there's a strong chance only some of your request is making it to the server which causes the 500 response.

The [`HttpRequestMessage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httprequestmessage(v=vs.118).aspx) class helps handle a lot of the things you're doing here manually such as form/url encoding your content and setting the content headers. See my example below. I've got a good feeling your code wasn't working due to the way you were manually writing to your request stream. If the below doesn't fix it, perhaps your request data is invalid.

```
IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> Data = new[] {
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("bResultat", "true"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ModeAffichage", "COMPLET"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("bImpression", ""),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("AERO_Date_DATE", "2018/10/03"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("AERO_Date_HEURE", "20:50"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("AERO_Langue", "FR"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("AERO_Duree", "12"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("AERO_CM_REGLE", "1"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("AERO_CM_GPS", "2"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("AERO_CM_INFO_COMP", "1"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("AERO_Tab_Aero[0]", "EDDM")
};

HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://notamweb.aviation-civile.gouv.fr/Script/IHM/Bul_Aerodrome.php");
request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(Data);

HttpClient cli = new HttpClient();
var response = await cli.SendAsync(request);
var responseText = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
```